# ASUS STRIX RAID PRO Soundcard on Ubuntu 22.04 / problems with alsamixer and 5.1 over SPDIF

Tags: pulseaudio, 22.04, alsa, soundcard

i am trying to get 5.1 sound from SDPIF on this card. First obstacle:

1. alsamixer gives this error:

   ```
   alsamixer
   ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
   ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function 
   snd_func_card_inum returned error: Datei oder Verzeichnis 
   nicht gefunden
   ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating 
   strings
   ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function 
   snd_func_concat returned error: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht 
   gefunden
   ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating 
   name
   ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function 
   snd_func_refer returned error: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht  
   gefunden
   ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: Datei 
   oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
   ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL 
   default
   Fehler beim Öffen des Mixer-Gerätes: Datei oder Verzeichnis 
   nicht gefunden
   ```
2. aplay -L gives out this:

   ```
   null
   Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples 
   (capture)
   default
   Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
   samplerate
   Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
   speexrate
   Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
   jack
   JACK Audio Connection Kit
   oss
   Open Sound System
   pulse
   PulseAudio Sound Server
   upmix
   Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
   vdownmix
   Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple 
   spacialization
   hw:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
       STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       Direct hardware device without any conversions
   hw:CARD=CARD,DEV=1
       STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio #1
   Direct hardware device without any conversions
       hw:CARD=CARD,DEV=2
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio #2
       Direct hardware device without any conversions
       plughw:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       Hardware device with all software conversions
       plughw:CARD=CARD,DEV=1
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio #1
       Hardware device with all software conversions
       plughw:CARD=CARD,DEV=2
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio #2
       Hardware device with all software conversions
       sysdefault:CARD=CARD
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       Default Audio Device
       front:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       Front output / input
       surround21:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
       surround40:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
       surround41:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
       surround50:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
       surround51:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer 
       speakers
       surround71:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and 
       Woofer speakers
   iec958:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
       STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
       iec958:CARD=CARD,DEV=1
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio #1
       IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
       dmix:CARD=CARD,DEV=0
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio
       Direct sample mixing device
       dmix:CARD=CARD,DEV=1
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio #1
       Direct sample mixing device
       dmix:CARD=CARD,DEV=2
   STRIX SOUND CARD, USB Audio #2
       Direct sample mixing device
       usbstream:CARD=CARD
   STRIX SOUND CARD
       USB Stream Output
   ```

Answer (score -1):

1. i fixed simply by enabling my onboard soundcard in bios

to get at least stereo sound out of SPDIF from the Asus STRIX i followed this one:

[It was necessary to enable a second device for this card (1:1)](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=341535&start=20)

one ot these should give you sound:

```
aplay -D plughw:1,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
aplay -D plughw:1,1 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
aplay -D plughw:1,2 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

For me it was 1,1.

To enable the device in sound settings do:

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,1
```

If that works, make it permamnent as the post above suggests:

open:
/etc/pulse/default.pa

and add at the end of the file:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,1
```

After rebooting the "new" device was still present in sund settings and i got stereo sound via SPDIF for now.

Now i need to figure out how i can enable 5.1....